# Python regex matching Unicode properties

Tags: python, regex, unicode, ucd, character-properties

Perl and some other current regex engines support Unicode properties, such as the category, in a regex. E.g. in Perl you can use `\p{Ll}` to match an arbitrary lower-case letter, or `p{Zs}` for any space separator. I don't see support for this in either the 2.x nor 3.x lines of Python (with due regrets). Is anybody aware of a good strategy to get a similar effect? Homegrown solutions are welcome.

Comment: Actually, Perl supports **all** Unicode properties, not just the general categories. Examples include `\p{Block=Greek}, \p{Script=Armenian}, \p{General_Category=Uppercase_Letter}, \p{White_Space}, \p{Alphabetic}, \p{Math}, \p{Bidi_Class=Right_to_Left}, \p{Word_Break=A_Letter
}, \p{Numeric_Value=10}, \p{Hangul_Syllable_Type=Leading_Jamo}, \p{Sentence_Break=SContinue},` and around 1,000 more. Only Perl’s and ICU’s regexes bother to cover the full complement of Unicode properties. Everybody else covers a tiny few, usually not even enough for minimal Unicode work.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Have you tried [Ponyguruma](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/ponyguruma/), a Python binding to the [Oniguruma](http://www.geocities.jp/kosako3/oniguruma/) regular expression engine? In that engine you can simply say `\p{Armenian}` to match Armenian characters. `\p{Ll}` or `\p{Zs}` work too.

Comment: this module has not the same API as Python re module

Comment: Last commit to Ponyguruma module was apparently 2010 (http://dev.pocoo.org/hg/sandbox/ponyguruma) whereas the Python regex module on PyPI is actively developed: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex

Answer (score 78):

The [regex](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) module (an alternative to the standard `re` module) supports Unicode codepoint properties with the `\p{}` syntax.

Comment: Not sure how complete the ``\p{}`` support is, but this module is actively developed and should eventually replace the built-in ``re`` module: see http://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex

Comment: +1: `regex` is a drop-in replacement for stdlib's `re` module. If you know how to use `re`; you immediately can use `regex`. `import regex as re` and you have `\p{}` syntax support. Here's an [example how to remove all punctuations in a string using `\p{P}`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11066687)

Comment: @RichVel When you say that regex "should" eventually replace the built-in `re` module, did you mean that there are plans for it to do so? I would like to have access to Unicode `\p{}` properties without the dependency. (It causes problems with pypy and pyodide.)

Comment: @yig that was just my personal opinion, not sure if anything's changed since 2013

Comment: @RichVel there are three approaches: 1) use the _Regex_ module; 2) use _PyICU_, and `icu.RegexMatcher()` which gives access to all Unicode properties, or 3) use _PyICU_ and `icu.UnicodeSet()`  using set operations to create sets of characters that can be used with _re_ or _regex_ as patterns.

Answer (score 7):

You can painstakingly use unicodedata on each character:

```
import unicodedata

def strip_accents(x):
    return u''.join(c for c in unicodedata.normalize('NFD', x) if unicodedata.category(c) != 'Mn')
```

Comment: Thanks. Although outside regex's, this might be viable alternative for certain cases.

Comment: It seems that the Python `unicodedata` module doesn't presently contain information about e.g. the script or Unicode block of a character. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48058402/unicode-table-information-about-a-character-in-python/48060112#48060112

Answer (score 6):

Speaking of homegrown solutions, some time ago I wrote a small [program](http://difnet.com.br/opensource/unicode_hack.py.txt) to do just that - convert a unicode category written as `\p{...}` into a range of values, extracted from the unicode [specification](http://unicode.org/versions/Unicode5.0.0/) (v.5.0.0). Only categories are supported (ex.: `L`, `Zs`), and is restricted to the BMP. I'm posting it here in case someone find it useful (although that Oniguruma really seems a better option).

Example usage:

```
>>> from unicode_hack import regex
>>> pattern = regex(r'^\\p{Lu}(\\p{L}|\\p{N}|_)*')
>>> print pattern.match(u'ÁñÇ_1+2').group(0)
ÁñÇ_1
>>>
```

Here's the [source](http://difnet.com.br/opensource/unicode_hack.py). There is also a [JavaScript version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8933546/520779), using the same data.

Comment: Nice one, although you're using hand-crafted literals for the ranges in the code. It would be nice to have those literals be generated from some textual form of the spec. Or from unicodedata (http://docs.python.org/library/unicodedata.html#module-unicodedata). You could probably run through all valid unicode code points and run them through unicodedata.category(), and use the output to populate the map ...

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I may implement that someday. The code above was created for JavaScript first (for which there were few sensible alternatives at the time), then ported to Python. I ran some regexes on the specs and finished with a throwaway script, but I agree a repeatable procedure would have been better, so I can keep it up-do-date.

Comment: I've hacked up a quick function that builds up the map dynamically (with just lists of chars as values):
    def unicats(maxu):
        m = defaultdict(list)
        for i in range(maxu):
           try: cat=unicodedata.category(unichr(i))
           except: cat=None
           if cat: m[cat].append(i)
        return m
    m=unicats(10FFFF)
Be aware that some categories get really big (e.g. len(m['Cn']) == 873882).

Answer (score 5):

You're right that Unicode property classes are not supported by the Python regex parser.

If you wanted to do a nice hack, that would be generally useful, you could create a preprocessor that scans a string for such class tokens (`\p{M}` or whatever) and replaces them with the corresponding character sets, so that, for example, `\p{M}` would become `[\u0300–\u036F\u1DC0–\u1DFF\u20D0–\u20FF\uFE20–\uFE2F]`, and `\P{M}` would become `[^\u0300–\u036F\u1DC0–\u1DFF\u20D0–\u20FF\uFE20–\uFE2F]`.

People would thank you. :)

Comment: Right, creating character classes crossed my mind. But with roughly 40 categories you end up producing 80 classes, and that's not counting unicode scripts, blocks, planes and whatnot. Might be worth a little open source project, but still a maintenance nightmare. I just discovered that re.VERBOSE doesn't apply to character classes, so no comments here or white space to help readability...

Answer (score 4):

Note that while `\p{Ll}` has no equivalent in Python regular expressions, `\p{Zs}` should be covered by `'(?u)\s'`.
The `(?u)`, as the docs say, “Make \w, \W, \b, \B, \d, \D, \s and \S dependent on the Unicode character properties database.” and `\s` means any spacing character.

Comment: You're right. Problem is, '(?u)\s' is larger than '\p{Zs}', including e.g. newline. So if you really want to match only space separators, the former is overgenerating.

Comment: @ThomasH: to get "space except not newline" you can use the double-negated character class: `(?u)[^\S\n]`