# How to check unicode string to be letters, spaces and dashes only

Tags: python, regex

I've read a great solution for unicode strings [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6314634/236964), but I need to check entire string to be letters or spaces or dashes and I can't think of any solution. The example is not working as I want.

```
name = u"Василий Соловьев-Седой"
r = re.compile(r'^([\s\-^\W\d_]+)$', re.U)
r.match(name) -> None
```

Comment: Please define exactly what you mean by "letters", "spaces", and "dashes".

Comment: letters - any unicode letters, spaces - space :), dashes - "-" symbol

Comment: I think he means [a-zA-Z[UNICODE_LETTERS] -]*, the problem here is [UNICODE_LETTERS] right ?

Comment: @Eregrith, no. To check only unicode letters in string it is enough a r = re.compile(r'[^\W\d_]', re.U). It will work for string< for example, u"Василий", but will not work for u"Василий Соловьев-Седой"
. So I add "\s\-" to regex string, but it does not matching my string at all. I think there is error in my regex string, but I don't know where.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
r = re.compile(r'^(?:[^\W\d_]|[\s-])+$', re.U)
```

`[^\W\d_]` matches any letter (by matching any alphanumeric character except for digits and underscore).

`[\s-]` of course matches whitespace and dashes.

Comment: Did you test this on string u"Василий Соловьев-Седой"? I've got None in result.

Comment: @Tim in researching this I found your other answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716609/how-to-match-cyrillic-characters-with-a-regular-expression can you explain the difference? Is it that the re.U allows the word token \W to act the same was as the \p unicode token?

Comment: My mistake. I test regex on wrong string. @Tim your solution works perfect. Thanks.

Comment: @DavidHall: In a way, yes. Python doesn't support Unicode properties directly, but the `\w` shortcut is Unicode-aware (if you use `re.U`).

Answer (score 0):

if you ONLY want to check:

```
name = u"Василий Соловьев-Седой";
name = name.replace("-","").replace(" ",""); 
name.isalpha()
```