# Python, remove all non-alphabet chars from string

Tags: python, regex

I am writing a python MapReduce word count program. Problem is that there are many non-alphabet chars strewn about in the data, I have found this post [Stripping everything but alphanumeric chars from a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1276764/stripping-everything-but-alphanumeric-chars-from-a-string-in-python) which shows a nice solution using regex, but I am not sure how to implement it

```
def mapfn(k, v):
    print v
    import re, string 
    pattern = re.compile('[\W_]+')
    v = pattern.match(v)
    print v
    for w in v.split():
        yield w, 1
```

I'm afraid I am not sure how to use the library `re` or even regex for that matter. I am not sure how to apply the regex pattern to the incoming string (line of a book) `v` properly to retrieve the new line without any non-alphanumeric chars.

Suggestions?

Comment: `v` is an entire line of a book (specifically moby dick), I am going word by word not char by char. So some words might have a "," at the end so "indignity," does not map with "indignity".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stripping everything but alphanumeric chars from a string in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1276764/stripping-everything-but-alphanumeric-chars-from-a-string-in-python)

Comment: Lolx - did you get the same pre-interview home exercise as me? Find the 50 most used words in Moby Dick and report their frequency. I did it in C++, IIRC

Comment: @Mawg It was an exercise in my undergrad "Cloud Computing" class.

Answer (score 179, accepted):

Use [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.sub)

```
import re

regex = re.compile('[^a-zA-Z]')
#First parameter is the replacement, second parameter is your input string
regex.sub('', 'ab3d*E')
#Out: 'abdE'
```

Alternatively, if you only want to remove a certain set of characters (as an apostrophe might be okay in your input...)

```
regex = re.compile('[,\.!?]') #etc.
```

Comment: Hmm, I can quite track it down, but what about the pattern to remove all non-alphanumerics excluding spaces?

Comment: Just add a space into your collection class.  i.e. ```^a-zA-Z ``` instead of just ```^a-zA-Z```

Comment: Unless you're also worried about newlines, in which case ```a-zA-Z \n```.  I'm trying to find a regex that would lump both into one but using ```\w``` or ```\W``` isn't giving me the desired behavior.  You might just need to add ```\n``` if that's the case.

Comment: Ahh, the newline char. Thats where my issues lies, I was comparing my results to given results and I was still off. I think that's my issue! Thanks // Hmm, I tried it with the newline char same results, I think there is another I am missing.. // Duhhh... Upper and lower case... // Thanks for all the help, works perfectly now!

Answer (score 72):

If you prefer not to use regex, you might try

```
''.join([i for i in s if i.isalpha()])
```

Comment: how do I join this? with ''.join ? printing s gets only a filter object

Comment: Wow, this is what i was looking. This takes into account kanji, hiragana, katakana,etc. kudos

Answer (score 47):

Try:

```
s = ''.join(filter(str.isalnum, s))
```

This will take every char from the string, keep only alphanumeric ones and build a string back from them.

Comment: This good, because it can handle strange characters like Å Å Ö

Comment: if someone does not want to keep numbers use `isalpha`instead of `isalnum`. And if you want to keep spaces you can do `''.join(filter(lambda x: x.isalpha() or x.isspace(), s))`

Answer (score 42):

You can use the re.sub() function to remove these characters:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub("[^a-zA-Z]+", "", "ABC12abc345def")
'ABCabcdef'
```

re.sub(MATCH PATTERN, REPLACE STRING, STRING TO SEARCH)

- `"[^a-zA-Z]+"` - look for any group of characters that are NOT
  a-zA-z.
- `""` - Replace the matched characters with ""

Comment: Note that this will also remove accented letters: ãâàáéèçõ, etc.

Answer (score 10):

The fastest method is regex

```
#Try with regex first
t0 = timeit.timeit("""
s = r2.sub('', st)

""", setup = """
import re
r2 = re.compile(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9]', re.MULTILINE)
st = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz123456789!@#$%^&*()-=_+'
""", number = 1000000)
print(t0)

#Try with join method on filter
t0 = timeit.timeit("""
s = ''.join(filter(str.isalnum, st))

""", setup = """
st = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz123456789!@#$%^&*()-=_+'
""",
number = 1000000)
print(t0)

#Try with only join
t0 = timeit.timeit("""
s = ''.join(c for c in st if c.isalnum())

""", setup = """
st = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz123456789!@#$%^&*()-=_+'
""", number = 1000000)
print(t0)


2.6002226710006653 Method 1 Regex
5.739747313000407 Method 2 Filter + Join
6.540099570000166 Method 3 Join
```

Answer (score 3):

It is advisable to use [PyPi `regex` module](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) if you plan to match specific Unicode property classes. This library has also proven to be more stable, especially handling large texts, and yields consistent results across various Python versions. All you need to do is to keep it up-to-date.

If you install it (using `pip install regex` or `pip3 install regex`), you may use

```
import regex
print ( regex.sub(r'\P{L}+', '', 'ABCŁąć1-2!Абв3§4“5def”') )
// => ABCŁąćАбвdef
```

to remove all chunks of 1 or more characters other than Unicode letters from `text`. See an [online Python demo](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRKEoNT21gqsktaJEwVZB3dHJ@WjjkdYj7Ya6RooXJlzYeGGT8aHlJo8a5pimpKY9apirDlMK1qdXXJqkUaQeE1DtU6utrqOgDsQgeU2ugqLMvBINMPv/fwA). You may also use `"".join(regex.findall(r'\p{L}+', 'ABCŁąć1-2!Абв3§4“5def”'))` to get the same result.

In Python `re`, in order to match any Unicode letter, one may use the `[^\W\d_]` construct ([Match any unicode letter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6314614)).

So, to remove all non-letter characters, you may either match all letters and join the results:

```
result = "".join(re.findall(r'[^\W\d_]', text))
```

Or, remove all chars matching the `[\W\d_]` pattern (opposite to `[^\W\d_]`):

```
result = re.sub(r'[\W\d_]+', '', text)
```

See the [regex demo online](https://regex101.com/r/7U3dTo/6). **However**, you may get inconsistent results across various Python versions because the Unicode standard is evolving, and the set of chars matched with `\w` will depend on the Python version. Using PyPi `regex` library is highly recommended to get consistent results.

Answer (score 1):

Here's yet another callable function that removes every that is not in plain english:

```
import re
remove_non_english = lambda s: re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z\s\n\.]', ' ', s)
```

Usage:

```
remove_non_english('a€bñcá`` something. 2323')
> 'a b c    something     '
```