# How remove non alphanumerical characters from int and string in python

Tags: python-2.7

Is there any simple function, such as .replace("", " "), that removes non alphanumeric characters? 
I want to,for example, remove "-" or other kinds of non alphanumeric characters from an input.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stripping everything but alphanumeric chars from a string in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1276764/stripping-everything-but-alphanumeric-chars-from-a-string-in-python)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python, remove all non-alphabet chars from string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22520932/python-remove-all-non-alphabet-chars-from-string)

Comment: one simple solution would be this: [filter isalnum](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27773789/2162347)

Comment: does it work for int, because the input is going to be a phone number, and i want tor remove "-" for example if the user writes 055-56753 @Dragos

Comment: @michaelMekonnen you can check for yourself here: [Python Manual](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=isalnum#str.isalnum)