# Computer lengths of words inside string of a list Python

Tags: python, string, list, mean

Im looking for a way to be able to calculate the mean number of letters per each sentence in my list. Im trying to split the strings by white space and then count the length of each word inside but im not able to.

Any guidance would be helpful.

[image: Example of different strings in list]

Comment: Average *word* length? Or *sentence* length?

Comment: Ive tried iterating through the python and splitting on white space but receive errors whenver i try to. And i meant average sentance length.

Comment: So basically i want ('This is a test', 'Another test') would return (2.75, 5.5) respectively

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not going to write the code for you, but this will probably help. If I am understanding the question correctly you are trying to take a big block of text (paragraph) split it into sentences then get the average len of characters in each sentence.

So:

1) Break text block into sentences. [Here is a post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576077/python-split-text-on-sentences) that should help you do that.

2) Count the letters in a sentence. [Here is another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8270092/python-remove-all-whitespace-in-a-string) that will help remove the whitespace from the sentence. If you need to remove all the punctuation (everything except letters) from the string check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22520932/python-remove-all-non-alphabet-chars-from-string). Now you have a string that you can simply do a `len(sentence_string)` to get how many characters are in the sentence.

Next time please post the code you have tried, the errors you have gotten, and the text of the data you are trying to use. DON'T post pictures of words. It makes it a lot harder to help when we can't just copy and paste everything and debug it ourselves.

Answer (score 0):

This code would work:

```
word = sentence.split(' ')
total = 0
for i in word:
    total += len(i)
return float(total)/len(word)
```

The code splits on whitespace, then adds the length of the words and divides by the number of the words in the sentence. This calculates the average.