# Removing non-alphabetical characters from a list element in python

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, list

Given a list

```
['R2', 'Y1-1', 'Y1-2', 'Y2-1', 'Y2-2', 'r']
```

i wish to remove all non-alphabetical characters and return the list in the form

```
['R', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'r']
```

Is there a way of doing this in python 3.6.3?

Comment: No this is completely impossible in Python... :).

Comment: start to write some code, like `for item in yourlist: ...`

Comment: I don't think the currently marked duplicate is correct. It so happens the example the OP gave is answered by that. However, he clearly states he wants all non-alphanumerical characters removed. Two such duplicates are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22520932/python-remove-all-non-alphabet-chars-from-string) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1276764/stripping-everything-but-alphanumeric-chars-from-a-string-in-python)

Comment: Thanks. Solved using
newlist = [item.rstrip('0123456-') for item in oldlist]

print (newlist)