# Removing parenthesis from string with regex

Tags: python, regex

I have this word: `word = 'ROTONDE04)'`. I would like to clean it and keep only letters.

Therefore I tried:

```
>>> re.search('[^a-zA-Z].', word)
<re.Match object; span=(7, 9), match='04'>
```

Why is the parenthesis not returned by `re.search`? It does not belong to my class `[^a-zA-Z]`.

I would like to avoid using `re.sub`.

Comment: This regex searches from the beginning of the string for any character that is not `a-z` or `A-Z` and then any other character (`.`). It matches on `04` and then stops searching. Can you explain why you thought it would do something different?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I find all matches to a regular expression in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697882/how-can-i-find-all-matches-to-a-regular-expression-in-python)

Comment: Or this? [Python, remove all non-alphabet chars from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22520932/python-remove-all-non-alphabet-chars-from-string)

Comment: The second link seems better, Why does it stop searching after `04` ?

Comment: Because that's what [`re.search` is supposed to do](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search). See the first link for alternatives.

Comment: Why are you willing to use `re.search` but not `re.sub`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've specified two characters to match:

1. Any character that isn't a letter (`[^a-zA-Z]`), immediately followed by
2. Any character at all (`.`)

The first time in the string that this criteria is met is `04`.

You may wish to match *strings at least one character long that do not contain letters*, in which case you want `+` instead of `.`:

```
>>> re.search('[^a-zA-Z]+', word)
<re.Match object; span=(7, 10), match='04)'>
```

The `*` character would be used instead of `+` if you wanted to match *zero or more occurrences*, instead of *one or more occurrences*. In this case, using `*` instead of `+` produces an empty string, as it matches at the very beginning.

Comment: why using the the `*` returns an empty string ? Is it because it searches only a potential match at the begining ?

Comment: `re.search()` searches from the beginning of the string and finds the first satisfying occurrence it can. Since the empty string at the very beginning would satisfy `[^a-zA-Z]*`, it returns that.