# Pandas: How to remove character that include non english characters?

Tags: python, pandas

In my DF there are values like `Ø§Ù„ÙØ¬ÙŠØ±Ø©` in different columns. How can I remove such values? I am reading the data from an excel file. So on reading, if we could do something then that will be great.

Also, I have some values like `Battery ÁÁÁ` so I want it to be `Battery`, So how can I delete these non-English characters but keep other content?

Comment: Do you mean non-*Latin* characters, or perhaps non-ASCII characters?

Comment: I don't know what these are called. a-z A-Z 0-9 and @#$%&*()[];',. except all these

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can use regex to remove designated characters from your strings:**

```py
import re
import pandas as pd

records = [{'name':'Foo Ø§Ù„ÙØ¬ÙŠØ±Ø©'}, {'name':'Battery ÁÁÁ'}]
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(records)


# Allow alpha numeric and spaces (add additional characters as needed)
pattern = re.compile('[^A-z0-9 ]+')
def clean_text(string):
    return pattern.search('', string)

# Apply to your df
df['clean_name'] = df['name'].apply(clean_text)

                name clean_name
0  Foo Ø§Ù„ÙØ¬ÙŠØ±Ø©       Foo
1        Battery ÁÁÁ   Battery
```

> For more solutions, you can read this SO Q: [Python, remove all non-alphabet chars from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22520932/python-remove-all-non-alphabet-chars-from-string)

Answer (score 0):

You can use python split method to do that or **you can lambda function:**

```
df[column_name] = df[column_name].apply(lambda column_name : column_name[start:stop])
#df['location'] = df['location'].apply(lambda location:location[0:4])
```

**Split Method**

```
df[column_name] = df[column_name].apply(lambda column_name: column_name.split('')[0])
```