# Regex Get All Alphabetic characters

Tags: python, regex, special-characters

I want something like `[A-z]` that counts for all alphabetic characters plus stuff like `ö`, `ä`, `ü` etc.

If i do `[A-ü]` i get *probably* all special characters used by latin languages but it also allows other stuff like `¿¿]|{}[¢§øæ¬°µ©¥`

Example: https://regex101.com/r/tN9gA5/2

**Edit:**
I need this in python2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `[A-z]`, you are not only capturing letters from "A" to "z", you also capture some more non-letter characters: `` [ \ ] ^ _ ` ``.

In Python, you can use `[^\W\d_]` with `re.U` option to match Unicode characters (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6314614/match-any-unicode-letter)).

[Here is a sample](https://regex101.com/r/tN9gA5/3) based on your input string.

Python example:

```
import re
r = re.search(
    r'(?P<unicode_word>[^\W\d_]*)',
    u'TestöäüéàèÉÀÈéàè',
    re.U
)

print r.group('unicode_word')
>>> TestöäüéàèÉÀÈéàè
```

Answer (score 4):

Depending on what regular expression engine you are using, you could use the `^\p{L}+$` regular expression. The `\p{L}` denotes a unicode letter:

> In addition to complications, Unicode also brings new possibilities.
>   One is that each Unicode character belongs to a certain category. You
>   can match a single character belonging to the "letter" category with
>   \p{L}

[Source](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html)

[This](https://regex101.com/r/jW2dC7/1) example should illustrate what I am saying. It seems that the regex engine on Regex101 does support this, you just need to select PCRE (PHP) fromo the top left.

Comment: this is probably the best idea but i am using python and the standard regex library does not support this.