# How to tokenize, splitting the adjacent digit-letter?

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to tokenize something like `hello world123` into `hello`, `world` and `123`.
I have the two parts of the code that are needed, I think, but cannot combine them to properly `tokenize`.

```
(?u)\b\w+\b
(?<=\D)(?=\d)|(?<=\d)(?=\D)
```

Comment: The first regex extracts whole words consisting of letters, digits and underscores (and there are some other Unicode categories included, but that is basically what `\w` matches) and the second one splits digits from non-digits. I think all you want is to match streaks of 1 or more letters or of 1or more digits. See my solution below.

Comment: Thanks, this is really helpful. Maybe to add to the complexity a little, how can we separate something like 1.5mL into "1.5" and "mL"

Comment: [`[^\W\d_]+|\d+(?:\.\d+)?`](https://regex101.com/r/8qAxP4/1/)

Comment: Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
import re
s = "hello world123"
print(re.findall(r'[^\W\d_]+|\d+', s))
# => ['hello', 'world', '123']
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/RjRaWT)

**Pattern details**

- `[^\W\d_]+` - 1 or more letters
- `|` - or
- `\d+` - 1+ digits.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7ZZsIO/2).

**BONUS**: To match any letter substrings and numbers of various kinds use

```
[^\W\d_]+|[-+]?\d*\.?\d+(?:[eE][+-]?\d+)?
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8qAxP4/2).

See [Parsing scientific notation sensibly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/638565/parsing-scientific-notation-sensibly) for the regex details.

Comment: and there may be a subtle difference between `[^\W\d_]` and `[A-Za-z]` I suppose, for localized accentuated letters

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Yes, also, here is a [relevant thread about `[^\W\d_]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6314614/match-any-unicode-letter). For Python 2 users, to make it fully Unicode-aware, `re.U` flag (or its inline `(?u)` embedded flag) is necessary (the behavior is default in Python 3). And, in those scenarios, to match only ASCII digits, `[0-9]+` would be more appropriate than `\d+` that will match all Unicode digits.