# Regexp match word but allow for nonlatin letters

Tags: javascript, regex, latin

```
const myWord = "ölkorv";

myWord.replace(/\w\S*/g, function(txt) {
        return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();
});
```

This returns: "öLkorv". So basicly I understand that `\w` will only match on latin letters, how would I accomplish the same thing but allow of ÅÄÖ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6314614/match-any-unicode-letter

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280712/javascript-unicode-regexes Also here are some answers