# python unicode regex

Tags: python, regex, unicode, uri, character-properties

I'd like to replace the below regex with a unicode-friendly version that will catch things like [http://➡.ws](http://%E2%9E%A1.ws) and other non-ascii [IRIs](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3987). The purpose is to grab these out of users' text and encode and html-ize them into real links.

Python provides a re.UNICODE flag which changes the meaning of \w, but that's not super helpful in this case (that I can see) because it is defined as "alphanumeric characters and underscore" and not all of my below character classes include underscore.

```
domain_regex = re.compile(r"""
    (
        (https?://)
        (
            [0-9a-zA-Z]
            [0-9a-zA-Z_-]*
            \.
        )+
        [a-zA-Z]{2,4}
    )
    | # begins with an http scheme followed by a domain, or
    (
        (?<!   # negative look-behind
            [0-9a-zA-Z.@-]
        )
        (
            [0-9a-zA-Z]
            [0-9a-zA-Z_-]*
            \.
        )+
        # top-level domain names
        com|ca|net|org|edu|gov|biz|info|mobi|name|
        us|uk|fr|au|be|ch|de|es|eu|it|tv|cn|jp
    )
""", re.VERBOSE)
```

More non-ascii domains:

- [Bücher.ch](http://xn--bcher-kva.ch/) -- (swiss-german "books". Currently down.)
- [http://παράδειγμα.δοκιμή](http://xn--hxajbheg2az3al.xn--jxalpdlp/)
- [http://실례.테스트](http://xn--9n2bp8q.xn--9t4b11yi5a/)

Comment: This is a possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832893/python-regex-matching-unicode-properties Let us know if you need any more help

Answer (score 5):

If you want to write "\w except underscore" you can do so using a negated character class:

```
[^\W_]
```

Answer (score 0):

As buckley noted, ["Python regex matching Unicode properties"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1832893/520779) presents some alternatives to use regex + unicode in Python. If what you want is just **alphanumeric**,  **alphanumeric + underscore** or **letters only**, maybe it's easier to stick with Mark Byers suggestion (`[^\W_]`, `\w` and `[^\W\d_]` respectively, with `re.UNICODE` active; *Edit:* got the order wrong...).

Otherwise, look up which character classes are valid as a IRI part and either use a regex engine that supports unicode character classes, or - if you need a pure python solution - I'd suggest the code I provided in [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9552524/520779) to that question (or a similar solution).