# PHP PCRE regex to Python compatible

Tags: python, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python regex matching Unicode properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832893/python-regex-matching-unicode-properties)

I'm trying to port this line of code in PHP to Python:

```
preg_match_all('/\p{L}[\p{L}\p{Mn}\p{Pd}\'\x{2019}]*/u', $text, $tmp);
```

What I got:

```
tmp = re.split('\p{L}[\p{L}\p{Mn}\p{Pd}\'\u2019]*', text, flags=re.U)
```

But... Python's regular expression syntax doesn't supports `\p` - Unicode character properties!

Any alternative?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832893/python-regex-matching-unicode-properties