# Regexp for non-ASCII characters

Tags: python, regex, unicode, python-3.x

Consider this snippet using regular expressions in Python 3:

```
>>> t = "Meu cão é #paraplégico$."
>>> re.sub("[^A-Za-z0-9 ]","",t,flags=re.UNICODE)
'Meu co  paraplgico'
```

Why does it delete non-ASCII characters? I tried without the flag and it's all the same.

As a bonus, can anyone make this work on Python 2.7 as well?

Comment: I am using python 3.2

Comment: Because `a-z` is `abcdef...xyz` and this does not include `ã`. If you want all word characters, use `\w`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[In 1]: import regex
[In 2]: t = u"Meu cão é #paraplégico$."
[In 3]: regex.sub(r"[^\p{Alpha} ]","",t,flags=regex.UNICODE)
[In 4]: print(regex.sub(r"[^\p{Alpha} ]","",t,flags=regex.UNICODE))
```

> Meu cão é paraplégico

Answer (score 4):

You are substituting non-alphanumeric characters(`[^A-Za-z0-9 ]`) with blank(`""`). The non-ASCII characters are not among A-Z, a-z, or 0-9, so they get substituted.

You can match all word characters like this:

```
>>> t = "Meu cão é #paraplégico$."
>>> re.sub("[^\w ]","",t, flags=re.UNICODE)
>>> 'Meu cão é paraplégico'
```

Or you could add the characters into your regex like so: `[^A-Za-z0-9ãé ]`.

Comment: Yep, I got it! but What is the equivalent of A-Za-z in Unicode?

Comment: In many (other) languages you could use Unicode properties to define a regex of `[^\p{Alpha} ]`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832893/python-regex-matching-unicode-properties for alternatives in Python.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by switching to the regex library (from PyPI).

then the regex command became:

```
regex.sub(ur"[^\p{L}\p{N} ]+", u"", t)
```