# Python regex, remove all punctuation except hyphen for unicode string

Tags: python, regex, string

I have this code for removing all punctuation from a regex string:

```
import regex as re    
re.sub(ur"\p{P}+", "", txt)
```

How would I change it to allow hyphens? If you could explain how you did it, that would be great. I understand that here, correct me if I'm wrong, P with anything after it is punctuation.

Comment: @Jerry - I looked a little, and found this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4316097/7586 - This is `regex`, not `re`. I guess they have two.

Comment: @Kobi Oh... I guess that explains it.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
[^\P{P}-]+
```

`\P` is the complementary of `\p` - not punctuation. So this matches anything that is *not* (not punctuation or a dash) - resulting in all punctuation except dashes.

Example: http://www.rubular.com/r/JsdNM3nFJ3

If you want a non-convoluted way, an alternative is `\p{P}(?<!-)`: match all punctuation, and then check it wasn't a dash (using negative lookbehind).
Working example: http://www.rubular.com/r/5G62iSYTdk

Comment: Great, thanks. What about excluding multiple? Such as '.' as well.

Comment: @Anonymous - The first one would be `[^\P{P}\-.]+`, and the second `\p{P}(?<![\-.])`. Pretty straightforward.

Comment: Why was it necessary to have '\' now after {P} and not in the first?

Comment: @Anonymous - Good question! It isn't strictly *necessary* - I usually prefer to include it. `-` has a spacial meaning in character class, like in `[a-z]` - it indicated a range. I usually like to escape it, to avoid potential bugs.

Answer (score 25):

Here's how to do it with the `re` module, in case you have to stick with the standard libraries:

```py
# works in python 2 and 3
import re
import string

remove = string.punctuation
remove = remove.replace("-", "") # don't remove hyphens
pattern = r"[{}]".format(remove) # create the pattern

txt = ")*^%{}[]thi's - is - @@#!a !%%!!%- test."
re.sub(pattern, "", txt) 
# >>> 'this - is - a - test'
```

If performance matters, you may want to use `str.translate`, since [it's faster than using a regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/266162/6157047). In Python 3, the code is `txt.translate({ord(char): None for char in remove})`.

Comment: `re` here refers to [this module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex), which does have `\p`.

Comment: `txt.translate({}, chars_to_delete)` have a nicer syntax.

Comment: This is a great pythonic solution. +1

Comment: I tried this with a full stop (trying to retain the ending full stop), but it doesn't seem to work...? It does work with the txt.translate({ord(char): None for char in remove}) approach though.

Answer (score 0):

You could either specify the punctuation you want to remove manually, as in `[._,]` or supply a function instead of the replacement string:

```
re.sub(r"\p{P}", lambda m: "-" if m.group(0) == "-" else "", text)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
import re, string

text = ")*^%{}[]thi's - is - @@#!a !%%!!%- test."

exclusion_pattern = r"([{}])".format(string.punctuation.replace("-", ""))

result = re.sub(exclusion_pattern, r"", text)

print(result)
```

> 'this  is  a  test'