# Python removing punctuation from unicode string except apostrophe

Tags: python, regex, unicode, punctuation

I found several topics of this and I found this solution:

```
sentence=re.sub(ur"[^\P{P}'|-]+",'',sentence)
```

This should remove every punctuation except ', the problem is it also strips everything else from the sentence.

Example:

```
>>> sentence="warhol's art used many types of media, including hand drawing, painting, printmaking, photography, silk screening, sculpture, film, and music."
>>> sentence=re.sub(ur"[^\P{P}']+",'',sentence)
>>> print sentence
'
```

of course what I want is to keep the sentence without punctuation, and "warhol's" stays as is

Desired output:

```
"warhol's art used many types of media including hand drawing painting printmaking photography silk screening sculpture film and music"
"austro-hungarian empire"
```

Edit:
 I also tried using

```
tbl = dict.fromkeys(i for i in xrange(sys.maxunicode)
    if unicodedata.category(unichr(i)).startswith('P')) 
sentence = sentence.translate(tbl)
```

but this strips every punctuation

Comment: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21209024/python-regex-remove-all-punctuation-except-hyphen-for-unicode-string) it says it should everything that is punctuation except '

Comment: Oops, you are correct; not that versed in the new `regex` module constructs.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Specify all the elements you *don't* want removed, i.e. `\w`, `\d`, `\s`, etc. This is what the `^` operator means with in square brackets. (matches anything except)

```
>>> import re
>>> sentence="warhol's art used many types of media, including hand drawing, painting, printmaking, photography, silk screening, sculpture, film, and music."
>>> print re.sub(ur"[^\w\d'\s]+",'',sentence)
warhol's art used many types of media including hand drawing painting printmaking photography silk screening sculpture film and music
>>>
```

Comment: this works for apostrophe, how do I add more exceptions? like -  or something like ?

Comment: just add `\-` to the `ur"..`