# How to strip string from punctuation except apostrophes for NLP

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I am using the below "fastest" way of removing punctuation from a string:

```
text = file_open.translate(str.maketrans("", "", string.punctuation))
```

However, it removes all punctuation including apostrophes from tokens such as `shouldn't` turning it into `shouldnt`.

The problem is I am using NLTK library for stopwords and the standard stopwords don't include such examples without apostrophes but instead have tokens that NLTK would generate if I used the NLTK tokenizer to split my text. For example for `shouldnt` the stopwords included are `shouldn, shouldn't, t`.

I can either add the additional stopwords or remove the apostrophes from the NLTK stopwords. But both solutions don't seem "correct" in a way as I think the apostrophes should be left when doing punctuation cleaning.

Is there a way I can leave the apostrophes when doing fast punctuation cleaning?

Comment: why don't you exclude apostrophe from `string.punctuation`?

Comment: I didnt know that was possible, something like this? `string.punctuation.replace(" ' ", "")`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
>>> from string import punctuation
>>> type(punctuation)
<class 'str'>
>>> my_punctuation = punctuation.replace("'", "")
>>> my_punctuation
'!"#$%&()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~'
>>> "It's right, isn't it?".translate(str.maketrans("", "", my_punctuation))
"It's right isn't it"
```

Comment: Any way to replace the punctuation with a space or other character?

Answer (score 3):

Edited from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29930403/8873143).

```
import re

s = "This is a test string, with punctuation. This shouldn't fail...!"

text = re.sub(r'[^\w\d\s\']+', '', s)
print(text)
```

This returns:

> This is a test string with punctuation This shouldn't fail

Regex explanation:

`[^]` matches everything but everything inside the blockquotes
`\w` matches any word character (equal to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`)
`\d` matches a digit (equal to `[0-9]`)
`\s` matches any whitespace character (equal to `[\r\n\t\f\v ]`)
`\'` matches the character `'` literally (case sensitive)
`+` matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed

And you can try it [here](https://regex101.com/r/iAeuqB/13).

Comment: thanks for the detailed regex explanation! I've noticed regex to be very popular to solving NLP problems. I will need to do some studying at some point.

Answer (score 1):

What about using

```
text = file_open.translate(str.maketrans(",.", "  "))
```

and adding other characters you want to ignore into the first string.