# How can I customize what characters are filtered out using string.punctuation?

Tags: python, regex, string

I have a string with which I would like to remove all punctuation. I currently use:

```
import string
translator = str.maketrans('','', string.punctuation)
name = name.translate(translator)
```

However, for strings which are names this removed the hyphen also, which I would like to keep in the string. For Instance '\Fred-Daniels!" Should become "Fred-Daniels".

How can I modify the above code to achieve this?

Comment: `string.punctuation` is itself a string.  Can't you just remove `-` from `string.punctuation`?

Comment: Are you looking for a regex solution or any solution? Your tag has regex and there is an answer already that does this using regex.

Comment: If you agree with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21209024/python-regex-remove-all-punctuation-except-hyphen-for-unicode-string) solution that answers your question I will dupe it. Otherwise, the regex tag should be removed and you should specify that you want a non-regex solution just to ensure proper categorization is preserved with the questions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you'd like to exclude some punctuation characters from `string.puncation`, you can simply remove the ones you don't want considered:

```
>>> from string import punctuation
>>> from re import sub
>>> 
>>> string = "\Fred-Daniels!"
>>> translator = str.maketrans('','', sub('\-', '', punctuation))
>>> string
'\\Fred-Daniels!'
>>> string = string.translate(translator)
>>> string
'Fred-Daniels'
```

Note if it's only one or two characters you want to exclude, you should use `str.replace`. Otherwise, its best to just stick with `re.sub`.

Answer (score 3):

```
import string

PUNCT_TO_REMOVE = string.punctuation
print(PUNCT_TO_REMOVE) # Output : !"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~

# Now suppose you don't want _ in your PUNCT_TO_REMOVE

PUNCT_TO_REMOVE = PUNCT_TO_REMOVE.replace("_","")
print(PUNCT_TO_REMOVE) # Output : !"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^`{|}~
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the use case, it could be safer and clearer to explicitly list the valid characters:

```
>>> name = '\\test-1.'
>>> valid_characters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890- '
>>> filtered_name = ''.join([ x for x in name if x.lower() in valid_characters ])
>>> print(filtered_name)
test-1
```

Note that many people have names that include punctuation though, like "Mary St. Cloud-Stevens", "Jim Chauncey, Jr.", etc.