# Removing punctuation from string.punctuation

Tags: python, nltk

I would like to know how to remove some punctuation symbol from the following list

```
string.punctuation
Out: '!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~'
```

Specifically, I would like to remove `@?&#!^_` to use it here:

```
def pr(text):


#1 Remove Punctuationa
nopunc = [char for char in text if char not in string.punctuation]
nopunc = ''.join(nopunc)

#2 Remove Stop Words
clean = [word for word in nopunc.split() if word.lower() not in stopwords.words('english')]

return clean
```

Thank you in advance for your answers and advice.

Comment: What's wrong with your code?

Comment: I would need to remove some puctuation from string.punctuation. So in my code I should consider a limited version of string.punctuation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I customize what characters are filtered out using string.punctuation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45427439/how-can-i-customize-what-characters-are-filtered-out-using-string-punctuation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same way you are removing punctuation from the input string.

```
limited_punc = [char for char in string.punctuation if char in "@?&#!^_"]
nopunc = [char for char in text if char not in limited_punc]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#module-re)

```
re.sub("[@?&#!^_]", "", string.punctuation)
'"$%\'()*+,-./:;<=>[\\]`{|}~'
```