# Punctuation special sequence \p fails in regex

Tags: python, regex

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21209024/python-regex-remove-all-punctuation-except-hyphen-for-unicode-string) suggests using `\p` to match punctuation and the comments suggest it works. But I could not find it in the official documentation and this code fails for me in Python 2.7.10 or Python 3.7.0:

```
import re

s = """
ABCD?
"""

print("with p: " + str(re.search(r"\n[A-Z \\p]+\n", s)))
print("with ?: " + str(re.search(r"\n[A-Z ?]+\n", s)))
```

The result is:

```
with p: None
with ?: <_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x1039afbf8>
```

Does Python have a special sequence to match punctuation?

Comment: Use PyPi regex module and use `\p{P}` to match punctuation. There is `import regex as re` at the start.

Comment: Note there is an [answer showing how to do that with `re`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37708340/3832970).

Comment: Yes indeed, I missed that `regex` was another package.