# Exclude matching the period character in a [\W\d]+ regex

Tags: python, regex

I'd like to remove all from a string except alphabetic characters and periods.
I made the below function in python. How would I extend the regex so periods are NOT stripped from the string? This needs to work for unicode strings.

```
def normalize(self, text):
    text = re.sub(ur"(?u)[\W\d]+", ' ', text)
    print text
    return text
```

Comment: try `text = re.sub(ur"(?:(?!\.)[\W\d])+", ' ', text)`

Comment: What does the `(?u)` do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

change the semantics from 'strip everything in this group'  to 'strip everything that's not in this group' and use:

```
text = re.sub(ur"(?u)[^a-zA-Z\.]+", ' ', text)
```

**update**

i don't think the above mentioned solution will work with all unicode alphabet.
the [answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832893/python-regex-matching-unicode-properties) offer alternative modules to the builtin `re` that support unicode letter groups.

another option is combining the two approaches:

```
>>> text = '1234abcd.à!@#$'
>>> re.sub(ur'(?u)([^\w\.]|\d)+',' ',text)
' abcd.\xc3 '
```

Comment: edited. again it won't do the thing that op expects. See the plus at the last.

Comment: change your regex to `[^a-zA-Z\.]+`

Comment: ([^\w\.]|\d)+ does not work. it does not strip the numbers.

Comment: @Jabb it does for me, see added example input/output