# What is the regex to find any English words for find and replace mode of pywikibot

Tags: python, wikipedia-api, pywikibot

I wrote the following programme to delink the English words in [a ta.wikipedia page](https://ta.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=%E0%AE%95%E0%AF%81%E0%AE%B3%E0%AE%B5%E0%AE%BF_(%E0%AE%A4%E0%AE%BE%E0%AE%B5%E0%AE%B0%E0%AE%AE%E0%AF%8D)&curid=142855&diff=2156081&oldid=2037779). Delink means removal of square brackets which are before and after the English words. I am new to [PAWS](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/PAWS)(pywikibot). It seems that to removal can done by regex(A-Z,a-z). How?

```
import pywikibot
import re

    site = pywikibot.Site('ta', 'wikipedia')
    page = pywikibot.Page(site, title)
    page.text = page.text.replace('[[Eudicots]]','Eudicots')
    page.save()
```

Sorry for my English.English is a bridge language for me. I am not asking to debug.But how to avoid the following repeated type of code.
for example, the following 26 (alphabet) code helps to remove the [[ brackets.

```
page.text = page.text.replace('[[A','A')
page.text = page.text.replace('[[B','B')
page.text = page.text.replace('[[C','C')
likewise, A to Z
page.text = page.text.replace('[[X','X')
page.text = page.text.replace('[[Y','Y')
page.text = page.text.replace('[[Z','Z')
```

Then i have to remove lowercase which is always at the end of a word. Because, every word ends in lowercase. to remove lowercase, i have to write the following code,

```
    page.text = page.text.replace('a]]','a')
    page.text = page.text.replace('b]]','b')
    page.text = page.text.replace('c]]','c')
    page.text = page.text.replace('d]]','d')
     (likewise, for all the 26 English letters)
    page.text = page.text.replace('x]]','x')
    page.text = page.text.replace('y]]','y')
```

I think this is not good coding. So i want to use regex.
 I hope that i furnished the need for the wikimedia project.

In other words, I want to remove English word's brackets only not the English words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some PCRE-compatible regular expression libraries can match character classes based on their Unicode properties (e.g. `\p{Latin}` would match any character of a Latin script), but Python's `re` module does not. There are other Python modules which you could use instead ([this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832893/python-regex-matching-unicode-properties) has the details) but as long as you are only looking for ASCII characters it's easier to build your own character class: `[A-Za-z]` will match a single character which is within those ranges, and `re.sub('([A-Za-z])]]', '\\1', text)` will keep that character and discard the brackets.

Comment: But it removes ]] bracket only. see [ https://ta.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=%E0%AE%AA%E0%AE%AF%E0%AE%A9%E0%AE%B0%E0%AF%8D%3AInfo-farmer%2FPAWS&type=revision&diff=2156707&oldid=2156706]                                                                                                                                                                                                                     page = pywikibot.Page(site, title)
        page.text = re.sub('([A-Za-z])]]', '\\1', page.text)
        page.save()

Comment: And also, it should not remove the brackets of  interwiki links example, [[:en:Parkia speciosa]]

Comment: I'm sure it is not hard to combine to calls :) If you want them in a single regex, something like `(\[\[|]])(?![A-Za-z])` will work. Exempting interwikis is not something regexes are a good tool for. You can try `re.sub` with a callback but probably better to use something like [mwparserfromhell](https://github.com/earwig/mwparserfromhell).