# Python3 unicode regex

Tags: regex, python-3.x, python-unicode, cyrillic

I'm not a native English speaker, but it happened that I've never written any regex for any non-ASCII text in my life, so I'm confused with a seemingly trivial case.

I have a large dictionary scrapped from a website by a robot. All HTML tags are removed. My goal is to remove most carry over hyphens. The idea is that >90% of problematic punctuation have a form `lowercase-lowercase`, so they could be caught by regex like `'\p{Ll}-\p{Ll}'`. This should be able to capture Russian lowercase chars, `при-мер` for example.

However, it seems like `\p` isn't supported by python's `re` engine. I'm not sure which alternative regex engine I'm supposed to choose because googling doesn't show any information relevant to Python 3. I thought Python3 is much more advanced when it comes to i14n and Unicode, and it's supposed to have Unicode character class support.

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832893/python-regex-matching-unicode-properties

Comment: Use the `regex` module instead of `re`

Comment: So, the python 3 re doesn't support Unicode? Is there a reason for that? Compatibility?

Comment: Python3 supports unicode better than Python2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/1852463/886607 might be helpful.