# How to remove Modifier Letters from string

Tags: python, string

[Modifier letter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modifier_letter) are like [these](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/category/Lm); I am curious what is the most efficient way to remove them from a list of strings.

I know I can make a list, containing all these unicodes and run a for loop that goes through all of them against the string. I wonder how I can remove them using "re" package and perhaps specifying their range.

my string looks like

```
mystr = 'سلام خوبی dsdsd ᴶᴼᴵᴺ'
```

this is the unicode for 'ᴶ'

https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+1D36

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832893/python-regex-matching-unicode-properties. Basically, you need one of the solutions there to eliminate `\p{Lm}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find unicode categories here:

https://unicodebook.readthedocs.io/unicode.html

You can try this code (python3):

```
import unicodedata

inputData = u"سلام خوبی dsdsd ᴶᴼᴵᴺ"
print(u"".join( x for x in inputData if not unicodedata.category(x)=='Sk'))
```

Comment: turned out the regex solution : d = re.sub("\p{LM}", "", text) - is faster if the text is a long sentence - but for shorter text your method is superior - since this is the only available answer for now I accept yours. However, I will go ahead with regex

Answer (score 0):

Turned out the regex is faster for longer sentence

```
import unicodedata

inputData = u"سلام خوبی dxxxxxxxxxxsdsddxxxxxxxxxxsdsddxxxxxxxxxxsdsddxxxxxxxxxxsdsddxxxxxxxxxxsdsddxxxxxxxxxxsdsd ᴶᴼᴵᴺ"

a = time.time()
for i in range(1_000_000):
    d = u"".join( x for x in inputData if not unicodedata.category(x)=='Sk')

print(time.time() - a)
```

which took on my `2,4 GHz 8-Core Intel Core i9` - 17.69 second

```
import time
import regex as re

text = u"سلام خوبی dxxxxxxxxxxsdsddxxxxxxxxxxsdsddxxxxxxxxxxsdsddxxxxxxxxxxsdsddxxxxxxxxxxsdsddxxxxxxxxxxsdsd ᴶᴼᴵᴺ"

a = time.time()
for i in range(1_000_000):
    d = re.sub("\p{LM}", "", text)

print(time.time() - a)
```

took 6.1 second

if you use

```
u"سلام خوبی dxxxxxxxxxxsdᴶᴼᴵᴺ"
```

the regex approach is 6.08 second while the character level look is 5.08 second.