# Regex to match a list of one or more comma-separated words, unless the string ends in a comma

Tags: python, regex

I have written the following regex long time ago that must match at least 3 words and works in both Latin and Cyrillic characters : `regex = '([^ ,;\d]{2,}[ ,;]{1,}){2,}[^ ,;\d]{2,}'`

I would like to rewrite it to match `hello` but fail to match `hello,` because of the comma. However, I would still like it to match `hello, and, more, words`.

Example matches: `hello`, `hello, test69`, `hello, test69, matches`

Example non-matches: `hello,` `hello test69`, `hello test69 matches`

Comment: It's really not clear what you want, or why you are not using the obvious and simple `[^,]+`

Comment: @tripleee because we need the comma to be there, otherwise "two words" would match and we want it to fail, only match if it were "two, words" ... etc

Comment: You can use the [regex module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832893/python-regex-matching-unicode-properties) to specify the [Unicode category or script instead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html), eg `\p{Letter}+`, `\p{Latin}`, `\p{Cyrillic}`

Comment: Please review the [help] and in particular [How to ask](/help/how-to-ask) as well as the guidance for providing a [mre].

Comment: At least 3 whitespace/comma/semicolon-separated words containing 2 or more chars: `regex = r'\w{2,}(?:[\s,;]+\w{2,}){2,}'`. Does it solve the problem?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew the idea is to match any number of words that are comma separated, but fail if there is no comma between the words

Comment: Then use `r'\w+(?:\s*,\s*\w+)*'`

Comment: This would match both words that are and are not comma separated, and will fail for Cyrillic.

Comment: It will not fail for Cyrillic, `\w` matches any Unicode letters. Next, if you need to match at least two words, use `+` instead of `*` at the end, `r'\w+(?:\s*,\s*\w+)+'`

Comment: `[^,]+(,[^,]+)+` matches strings with one or more commas. It is still quite unclear what you are actually trying to accomplish.

Comment: @tripleee I want to match examples "one", "one, two", and fail to match examples "one," , "one two", "one, two," and etc. Your solution will fail at "one" but match at "one,".

Comment: So, [look here](https://regex101.com/r/0LbFdw/1), does `^\w+(?:, *\w+)*$` work now?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I would say that does work for all of OP's stated requirements, yes.

Comment: @TylerH Unless OP uses Python 2. Only in Python 2, `\w` does not match all Unicode letters.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that works great, do post is as an answer for future reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```py
^\w+(?:, *\w+)*$
```

In Python, you can use a shorter version if you use `re.fullmatch`:

```py
re.fullmatch(r'\w+(?:, *\w+)*', text)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0LbFdw/1).

**Note** that in case your spaces can be any whitespaces, replace the   with `\s` in the regex. If your words can only contain letters, replace each `\w` with `[^\W\d_]`. If your words can only contain letters and digits, replace every `\w` with `[^\W_]`.

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `\w+` - one or more word chars
- `(?:, *\w+)*` - zero or more repetitions of a comma, zero or more spaces, and then one or more word chars
- `$` - end of string.